# drupal facebook social plugin like and share button error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, drupal

I've the facebook like and share button on my drupal website via facebook social module. I've configured metatags module, and now facebooks picks correct image and content when I press share button, however it doesn't work for like button and comment plugin as well. When I go to facebook debug tool it shows the image and content of the share button. Also, it says "More Than One OG URL Specified" error.can this be the cause for the problem?

How can i make facebook to fetch correct content and image for like button Just like the share button does?

website url: www.photocopiables.com
Here are some pics or the problem:

[like error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXxDu.jpg)

[share pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtQm5.jpg)

thanks,

Comment: Can you add screen shots of what you are seeing? Do you have the URL of your website?

Comment: My website's url is www.photocoiables.com